# PHP - Using PHP to validate a form guarantees complete validation no matter what browser is the client?

Tags: php, validation

I have a relatively simple question.

Will using PHP guarantee that a form is always validated in the manner that was coded using PHP?

This being... If you do something like:

```
if (strlen($_POST['myInput'] == 0)
{
    Do this...
}
```

Will it apply no matter what client the user is making use of? E.g. IE, Firefox, Mobile Devices (Blackberry, Samsung), Linux Browsers?

The reason I ask this is because I fail to see the point in applying html validations like `pattern` at all.

Any input regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

```
if (!preg_match("#^([0-9 ]{10,13})?$#", $_POST['myInput']))
{
    // Apply error pointers
    $_SESSION['myInputError'] = 'class="badInput" autofocus="autofocus"';

    include "$docRoot/html/forms/reg/user_info.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The point of client-side validation is user friendliness.  The user gets to see the data is wrong and fix it immediately without having to submit the form.  (This gets way more useful with huge pages and forms with lots of data.)

Comment: But you can code this same effect quite easily using some well thought out php code? this would then be 100% compatible, excluding the css applications in this ofcourse.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your statement: "I fail to see the point in applying html validations like pattern at all" ?

Comment: @BlackberryFan: No, you can't.  You can make some PHP code that validates the same stuff, but in order for PHP to run, you have to have a postback.  At that point, you've defeated most of your goals.  What you do is have the PHP code to make sure the data's right before *you* use it, and the HTML/JS is mainly to help the user.  This is 100% compatible if you have half a clue about progressive enhancement and unobtrusive JS; the stuff that's not supported, just won't do anything.

Comment: @Johnathan, What I mean simply is that if you can apply things like css styles to any specific invalid input using php, or jump to it by applying autofocus... Along with the ability to process regex patterns and apply styles accordingly... I mean... Why use things like the html pattern attribute which is not very well supported in the first place?

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Consider:  If no one bothers to use the new features, browser makers won't feel any pressure to support them.  If browser makers don't support them, no one will feel any need to actually *use* them.  Someone's gotta break the inertial cycle.  Might as well be you.  :)

Comment: @cHao Please see the edit to my question

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Doesn't change anything.  In order for that PHP to run, the user has to post the form back to the server.  That's the biggest thing client-side validation is intended to avoid.  It's supposed to help the user get the data right before spending time and bandwidth posting a form and waiting for a response.  Now, *you* shouldn't be relying on the validation; some schmuck might have JS disabled or something.  Your PHP would take over and check the data in case the JS didn't work or did the wrong thing.

Comment: @cHao Well you see that is the basic point of my question then... I would like to know whether its actually worth applying html validations like that in the first place... It seems more time consuming than anything else, but I do see your point and it has been noted. You should add an answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, PHP is run by the server and not the client, therefor it will treat the input the same way always. So unless you make a specific code to make it act diffidently depending on the client's browser, it'll treat the input the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In this case, is there really any point in applying other types of validation like using the html pattern attribute?

Comment: Client side validation like the HTML pattern attribute is for convenience only. Never rely on it. It can be done very quickly and simply helps guide the user to enter proper input, without having to take the time to connect to the server to properly validate.

Comment: As alex said, HTML/JS validation is and should only ever be for convenience or to guide the user. What happens on the user side, you can never control, but the server side is only ever accessed by you, the developer.

Answer (score 2):

Validation on the server side should guarantee that the form is always validated.  So if you only have time to develop one, pick server-side validation.

That said, client-side validation is useful because each form field individually can be validated in real-time as the user fills it out, so they can tell much more quickly whether they've filled it out correctly.